# Problems with dual boot and disk partitions in windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

My primary OS is Windows 8.1, and I dual booted it with Kali-Linux. Initially, I gave about 40 GB to Linux. Now I want to increase the space for Kali and planning on reinstalling it with increased size.

While doing the partitions I found unallocated partitions on each side of 1 MB partition and I can't add them up.

Note: While I was dual booting I booted the Linux in Legacy mode and my Windows ran in UEFI mode. So, I have switch modes each time I switch OS.

I first thought about deleting that 1 MB partition and merging all of them up. But, then I read that it contains EFI files and some sort of other important files.

I wanted to add the picture of the partitions, but I am not allowed yet. So [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3_Bf8ZXlMkUS3RiOG5DaTlVRUU/view?usp=sharing) is the link for the picture, it's in my drive.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You must be able to move the unallocated space elsewhere. Windows disk manager does not allow you to, but there are plenty that do allow.

I just found this page: http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/move-unallocated-space.html

And you can google for gparted (live cd/dvd)